# Maintain same icon size for fontawesome and Material icons

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome, google-material-icons

I wanna use both **Material icons** and **fontawesome** in my project but always I get inconsistent UI because of icons sizes

[image: result]

I found that material icons path doesn't respect the given width

[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?

Although i did try to scale the svg to it's container

```
   .editPanelInputLabelIcon {
        display: flex;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        svg {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
 <span className="editPanelInputLabelIcon"><svg>...</svg> </span>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you're using Sass or Less or another language for CSS?

Comment: yes I'm using scss